# Spring+hibernate Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

applicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">
 
 
 <bean id = "dataSource" 
  class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
  <property name="driverClass">  
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>  
        </property>  
        <property name="jdbcUrl">  
            <value>jdbc:mysql://Localhost:3306/newsql</value>  
        </property>  
        <property name="user">  
            <value>root</value>  
        </property>  
        <property name="password">  
            <value>123456</value>  
        </property>  
         <property name="maxPoolSize">  
            <value>30</value>  
        </property> 
          <property name="minPoolSize">  
            <value>5</value>  
        </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory" 
  class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
  <property name="configLocation" value = "classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>  
 </bean>
 
 <bean id = "userDaoImpl"
  class = "daoImpl.UserDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
 </bean>
</beans>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

s

s

```css
s
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
     
     
     
     <mapping resource="bean/*.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

s

```js
s
package bean;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import daoImpl.UserDaoImpl;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  UserDaoImpl userdaoImpl = (UserDaoImpl) context.getBean("userDaoImpl");
  System.out.println(userdaoImpl);
 }

}
```

s

```html
s
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/ser/Indirector
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
 at bean.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/ser/Indirector
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
 ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.ser.Indirector
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 19 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/ser/Indirector
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
 at bean.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/ser/Indirector
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
 ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.ser.Indirector
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 19 more
```

xml

Answer (score 1):

add c3p0 jar to classpath

In maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```